# Xrdp runs, but with error messages in log file

Tags: xrdp

I have installed Xrdp on an Ubuntu 22.04 system.  It works reasonably well, but it does produce unfathomable error messages in its log file, xrdp.log, upon service startup.  Here is an extract from the log file, showing one such service startup:

```
[20240109-16:12:43] [INFO ] starting xrdp with pid 462779
[20240109-16:12:43] [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1
[20240109-16:12:43] [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
[20240109-16:12:43] [INFO ] setting send buffer to 4194304 bytes
[20240109-16:12:43] [INFO ] send buffer set to 8388608 bytes
[20240109-16:12:43] [INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done
[20240109-16:12:43] [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET6 connection received from ::ffff:192.171.161.23 port 64136
[20240109-16:12:43] [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20240109-16:12:43] [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20240109-16:12:43] [ERROR] libxrdp_force_read: bad header length 3
[20240109-16:12:43] [ERROR] [ITU-T X.224] Connection Sequence: CR-TPDU (Connection Request) failed
[20240109-16:12:43] [ERROR] xrdp_sec_incoming: xrdp_iso_incoming failed
[20240109-16:12:43] [ERROR] xrdp_rdp_incoming: xrdp_sec_incoming failed
[20240109-16:12:43] [ERROR] xrdp_process_main_loop: libxrdp_process_incoming failed
[20240109-16:12:43] [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET6 connection received from ::ffff:192.171.161.23 port 64137
[20240109-16:12:43] [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20240109-16:12:43] [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20240109-16:12:43] [ERROR] libxrdp_force_read: bad header length 3
[20240109-16:12:43] [ERROR] [ITU-T X.224] Connection Sequence: CR-TPDU (Connection Request) failed
[20240109-16:12:43] [ERROR] xrdp_sec_incoming: xrdp_iso_incoming failed
[20240109-16:12:43] [ERROR] xrdp_rdp_incoming: xrdp_sec_incoming failed
[20240109-16:12:43] [ERROR] xrdp_process_main_loop: libxrdp_process_incoming failed
```

There is a block of 5 error messages, repeated a few lines later.  This happens at every startup.  I have tried setting `LogLevel=DEBUG` in the configuration file, xrdp.ini, but all this seems to achieve is a logging of all configuration values - it does not shed any more light on the error messages.

I also tried setting the logging level to TRACE.  This resulted in fewer INFO log messages, and they did not include the ERROR log messages.  Perversely, when I returned the logging level to INFO, the situation was the same: fewer INFO log messages, and no ERROR log messages.  A second restart of the xrdp service, without having changed any config, resulted in a partial restoration of the 5 ERROR log messages: there was only one block of them, instead of 2 identical ones.

I have tried Googling some of these error messages, but this has failed to turn up anything relevant.  Should I be concerned about them?  Should I really raise this on GitHub with the Xrdp maintainer?

Comment: Perhaps answering my own question, I've just discovered https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/2505, which has a lot in common with my situation (but isn't identical).  My system is running Microsoft Defender (mdatp) which might also be performing "local port scans" at intervals, although far less frequently than described in the post in the GitHub issue.

Comment: Continuing this conversation with myself ( :-) ), I've tried stopping the mdatp service, then restarting Xrdp.  This did not stop the 2 blocks of 5 error messages appearing in the log file.  So I don't think mdatp can be the cause.